# networking in java

Tags: java, networking

I want to check whether a machine is in the network or not using ip address, and I used

```
if (InetAddress.getByName(ip).isReachable(3000))
```

but by using this my complete project has become very slow even if an ip is reachable. After sometime it shows that it is not responding.
Is there any alternative to this method?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean `in network`? Do you mean in the local network (LAN)? Or currently connected? Or what?

Comment: Your answer is at http://stackoverflow.com/q/1272335/1250303

Comment: I mean the system is connected either by LAN or wireless connection. And I want to get ip's of currently connected systems

Comment: You can try creating different thread for checking machine(ip) status

Comment: Thanx @nandkumar  making a different thread worked..:)

Comment: @Deepti YMW! :) You can post your answer, so that it would be useful to other users!

Answer (score 1):

You just create a socket and try to connect to the node you want to check, if it throws exception , it means that node is currently unreachable.

Comment: I agree completely. The other way comprises trying to foretell the future. In general the best way to determine the availability of *any* resource is just to try to use it. +1

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem, but I am using another alternative solution
<strike>if you are using Windows OS</strike>.
Simply ping to that IP address
ping is respond in millisecond so your app need not wait.

if ping is respond with Respond texxt than do your stuff. Sample code:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"ping", your_ip_address});
BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
```

Comment: Why only if they are using Windows?

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta You amaze me :-|