# Is this a good method of checking whether a socket died in Java?

Tags: java, sockets, networking

I'm working on a Java hearbeat sensor, that just tells you if the other side died. I found [some code like so](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1272981/763029):

```
        isConnected = kkSocket.isConnected() &&
                      !kkSocket.isClosed() &&
                      InetAddress.getByName(serverAddress).isReachable(1000);
```

Is this a reliable method? I'm confused by the  line:

```
InetAddress.getByName(serverAddress).isReachable(1000);
```

What's that for - would it work if I'm testing on "localhost" (ie not a real networked example, just one machine)?    thanks

Comment: i'm not sure how to interpret "if the other side died", if you're working with an heart beat-sensor.
but to not get OT: where are you planning to get this working? local environment?

Comment: @Zhedar -  Well it should work for a networked example( i.e it should work if machines are random on Internet) . But I am developing in a  local environment - I can do 2 machine within the intranet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what you mean by "if the other side died".

Firstly, the `isConnected()` call is no use.  That simply asks whether the Socket was connected at some point in the past.  Period.

Secondly, the `isClosed()` call is no use.

Thirdly, the `isReachable()` call is of little use.  It does provide you some level of assurance that the host for the service is alive and reachable at the basic network level.  (Specifically, it tells you that ICMP Ping packets are reaching the host, and that the responses are coming back.)  However, this doesn't tell you if the TCP/IP connection to the service is alive, or if the service itself is still functioning properly.  Indeed, a host could respond to Ping packets, and refuse or ignore attempts to connect to the service.

In fact, the only way to sure that the service is really alive (in the useful sense) is to try to use it.  What this means will depend on the nature of the service.  For a typical synchronous service, you would write a request "message" to the socket outputstream, and then try to read the reply "message" from the input stream.  (You should make sure that you use a timeout when reading an writing...):

- If the service has terminated or the TCP/IP connection has broken, you should get an SocketException or similar.  (Note however that a broken TCP/IP connection doesn't necessarily mean that the service is not alive.  You may simply need to connect again.)
- If the service is "stuck", you are likely to get a timeout on the write or read.
- If there is a networking issue, you may get a timeout or you may get a SocketException of some kind.

If none of the above happens, you have an indication that your service is "alive", though it is possible that it is only "alive" for the kind of request that you sent.

Obviously, you also need to check that the response is expected.  For instance, a HTTP service that sends a 501 or 503 response for every request is not alive in a useful sense.

---

> What's that for - would `isReachable` work if I'm testing on "localhost" (ie not a real networked example, just one machine)?

I don't think there is a clear answer to that.  It would depend on whether the OS supports the ICMP protocol on a loopback network address.  I would not *expect* it to work, because AFAIK there is no real use-case for ICMP on loopback.

Answer (score 2):

None of it is any use at all. The `isConnected()` method tells you whether you ever called `connect()` (implicitly or explicitly) or received the socket via `accept()`; the `isClosed()` method tells you whether you ever called `close()`; the `isReachable()` method only tells you whether the *host* is reachable, and it does so at the cost of an extra TCP connection setup and teardown per successful call.

*None* of it has anything whatsoever to do with *the state of the connection*. The only reliable way to detect an error on a TCP connection is to try to write to it.

Comment: @StephenC Not so. If you're only reading, and there is no keepalive, there is no network activity at all. You can block forever. Only writes cause network activity, retries, etc that could either provoke the peer into sending a reset, or provoke the  local TCP stack into giving up on the connection.

Comment: Not it you read with a timeout.  Anyway, tt really depends what he means by "the other side died".

Comment: @StephenC Exactly so, but if you don't use a read timeout you can block until the universe runs down.

Comment: I'm focusing on what you said - `The only reliable way to detect an error on a TCP connection is to try to write to it.`  - So I guess the easiest way may be to run a daemon thread that keeps writing periodically?